# Converting PDF to an image using PyMuPDF

Tags: python, pdf, qpixmap, pymupdf

I have attempted to use PyMuPDF to covert a PDF document to an image, so that I can use it in openCV. However I have an attribute error come up when I try to save the image and I'm not sure how to get around this?

```
import fitz
pdf = fitz.open('cornwall.pdf')
page = pdf.load_page(0)
pix = page.get_pixmap()
pix.writeImage("cornwall_output.png")
```

> AttributeError: 'Pixmap' object has no attribute 'writeImage'

Comment: if you need that "in OpenCV", find a way to convert it to a numpy array. writing to file would be a terrible hack.

Answer (score 0):

use pil_save method instead
https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pixmap.html#Pixmap.pil_save

```py
import fitz
pdf = fitz.open('cornwall.pdf')
page = pdf.load_page(0)
pix = page.get_pixmap()
pix.pil_save("cornwall_output.png") 
# optional arg in this method:
# optimize=True
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard way to save a PyMuPDF `Pixmap`: `pix.save()`. There is a handful of possible image formats available in this case: PNG, PSD (Adobe Photoshop), PS (Postscript) and the less popular PAM, PBM, PGM, PNM, PPM. Use `pix.pil_save()` instead only if you need more alternatives (e.g. JPEG) or special features offered by Pillow.